# On images tap, open another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have 3 views within my view controller that's controlled by a `UISegmentControl` so once each is clicked, it switches between each views. Now keep in mind they are all stacked, 2 hidden initially, and it pretty much toggles to show/hide the others.

I'm trying to set it so that once an area is tapped within any of the 3 views, it opens another view controller. How would I do this for all 3 views within my view controller? My views consist of a bunch of `UIImages` to mimic a table list (it's a prototype app). Each view isn't taking up the whole screen, as I do have a titlebar up top, searchbar, and a tabcontroller on bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to your image (UIImageView components), you should probably add a UITapGestureRecognizer to all of them to detect the taps.

For instance in viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *img1TapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(displayViewController1:);
[imageView1 addGestureRecognizer:img1TapGestureRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *img2TapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(displayViewController2:);
[imageView2 addGestureRecognizer:img2TapGestureRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *img3TapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(displayViewController3:);
[imageView3 addGestureRecognizer:img3TapGestureRecognizer];
```

Then display your view controllers in the following methods:

```
- (void)displayViewController1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recog {}
- (void)displayViewController2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recog {}
- (void)displayViewController3:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recog {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  if ([touch view] == yourDesiredImage) {
    // Do something here
  }
}
```